# make text on x-axis as bold in google column charts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I am working on angularjs google column charts. I want to display the text on the horizontal axis as **bold**.I went through the API and they suggest to use **`bold:<boolean>`** which is not working in my code.Please suggest how to make labels on the x-axis as bold.

js code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');
      data.addRows([
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 am'}, 1],
        [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 am'}, 2],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10 am'}, 3],
        [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '11 am'}, 4],
        [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '12 pm'}, 5],
        [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: '1 pm'}, 6],
        [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: '2 pm'}, 7],
        [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: '3 pm'}, 8],
        [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: '4 pm'}, 9],
        [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: '5 pm'}, 10],
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Motivation Level Throughout the Day',
        bold:'true',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time of Day',
          format: 'h:mm a',
          bold:'true',
          viewWindow: {
            min: [7, 30, 0],
            max: [17, 30, 0]
          }
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)',
          bold:"true"
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
        document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

html code:

```
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make the x-axis **tick mark labels** bold use --> `hAxis.textStyle.bold`

```
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time of Day',
      format: 'h:mm a',
      textStyle: {
        bold:'true',
      },
      viewWindow: {
        min: [7, 30, 0],
        max: [17, 30, 0]
      }
```

to make the x-axis **title label** bold use --> `hAxis.titleTextStyle.bold`

```
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time of Day',
      format: 'h:mm a',
      titleTextStyle: {
        bold:'true',
      },
      viewWindow: {
        min: [7, 30, 0],
        max: [17, 30, 0]
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code in your options object
 `hAxis: {
      title: 'Time of Day',
      format: 'h:mm a',
      titleTextStyle : {bold: 'true'},
      viewWindow: {
        min: [7, 30, 0],
        max: [17, 30, 0]
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)',
      titleTextStyle : {bold: 'true'}
    }`